# How can i get random value from InlineResponse200

Tags: python, giphy-api

So I am trying to get a random value from the data that i get from gyphi api search. I tried this:
`

```
import giphy_client
import time
import random
from pprint import pprint
api_instance = giphy_client.DefaultApi()
api_key = "aqMkX2XKd7aCTM4pVRB7XXXXXX9ieep"
q = "banana"
api_response = api_instance.gifs_search_get(api_key, q)
pprint(random.choice(api_response))`
```

But it returns error: `TypeError: object of type 'InlineResponse200' has no len()`
And I have no idea what to do.
Sorry if this is dumb question, but I am new and couldn’t find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`api_response` is of type `InlineResponse200`.
Here is its spec: https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client/blob/master/docs/InlineResponse200.md

What you want is the data contained in this response, so you should do:

```py
pprint(random.choice(api_response.data))
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a way to get just the URL address of the GIF and to somehow get only the first GIF?

Comment: I suppose that would be `api_response.data[0].url`